# How to make a secure login system?

Tags: php, mysql, security, cookies

I am making some login system just for learning. The idea is that a user creates a account and enters informations like name, phone no etc a unique Id is given to each record, a session token which is a hash of phone no and current time is also stored. When the program verifies phone no and password during login it sets the session id as cookie and fetches information based on the session id which is unique index.
A new session id is given every time when the when the user log outs.
The leak is that anyone can copy the value of session id cookie and send a request to the server with that cookie data and can find the information. How can I make this secure?
Kindly give some suggestions.

Comment: *Don’t reinvent the wheel. This is more complex than you could possibly imagine.*

Comment: I agree with @BoristheSpider this question is very broad and maybe you can do some research online. Stackoverflow is for asking questions about your code, not asking for code.

Comment: To be frank, none of what you have said makes much sense. You focus enormous complexity on session generation - which is not where the problem lies. You talk not at all about password storage and verification. And you have not done anywhere near enough research about cookies and cookie options.

Comment: PHP generates session tokens automatically, you don't need to make your own or put them in cookies

Comment: What @ADyson said - with the caveat that you need to set the correct options on said cookie for things to be secure (secure, httpOnly and friends).

Comment: Thanks @ADyson sessions are also cookies and can be misused. There can be some another way probably :)

Comment: The obvious flaw in the above is that anybody can create the hash of a user's phone number and time of login, making sessions very easy to hijack. Secure authentication and session management is a very large topic with a lot of complexity.

Comment: @AryanKumar it's not really true though that "anyone" can steal a session cookie (as long as you set the security properly). You can only steal the one from your own machine. And once the session expires it has no value. And if the session ID itself is just random and isn't made up of anything sensitive (such as a phone number!) then it is not useful to anyone afterwards and isn't easy to forge

Answer (score 1):

> The leak is that anyone can copy the value of session id cookie and send a request to the server with that cookie data and can find the information.

This is not a leak. If someone can get other's cookie data, they may as well install a keylogger on their computer to steal the password. If you use HTTPS and generate a completely random session id instead of the method you mentioned, then everything is very secured and you need not worry about it.

Edit: You should also add `secure` to your cookie as you don't want to ever use HTTP when talking about security.

Comment: Under the assumption that the cookie has the right options. With the wrong options a trivial XSS attack can grab the cookie.

Comment: @BoristheSpider IMO, if the website has an XSS vuln then it's where the problem lies, not because of the wrong option on the cookie. If there is XSS vuln then anything can happen...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I also don't like you saying XSS attack as *trivial* because it really isn't

Comment: No. Because being vulnerable to XSS is exactly having the wrong cookie options. You have things backwards I’m afraid.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not aware of this. Would like to know what exactly wrong cookie option could lead to xss?

Comment: Not specifying domain and path correctly will lead to the cookie being attached to erroneous requests. Not specifying secure will lead to extraction in plain text. Not specifying httpOnly will lead to extraction in malicious scripts. There are more options that prevent more attack vectors.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The `secure` option definitely matters. domain doesn't matter as _specifying `Domain` is less restrictive than omitting it_ (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). path matter in specific situation if you host your website not on your own domain. `httpOnly` doesn't matter that much due to reason I explained above as you don't want XSS in the first place (yes it can act as a safety net but still xss alone can cause troubles as you can do ajax request to perform action as that user, e.g. change password, etc).